# I cannot download proTeXt on re-trial after an aborted first trial

Tags: installing, protext

I tried to download proTeXt from the TUG site. The internet connection was interrupted, and I could then not complete it. On trying again, however, I have not been able to access the site at all, try as I may.

Please how may I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

use

http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/protext

then you'll get a mirror.